# Angular 2 routing error

Tags: angularjs, angular

Following the  [routing chapter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html) of the Angular2 tutorial, i've added my own simple `TestLink` (below the original Dashboard and Heroes) but it breaks the app. Specifically, i created `test-link.component.ts` that exports `TestLinkComponent` and added corresponding parameters to `@RouteConfig` inside app.component.ts. Plunker is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/i0vIMj9tLXYrLfEug5tY). Now the app stucks at 'loading'. (i'm just starting with angular, so any advice on how to debug such issues would also be appreciated!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelled `TestLinkComponent` in `app.component.ts` line #8.

See edited plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ar5agUGUHTuWA1LH8cf7?p=preview